# Getting JsonMappingException when trying to deserialize Json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm getting an error when I try to map a json string to a DataProduct object:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A (through reference chain: DataProduct["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

This json string was created by being serialzed from the same DataProduct Object so I'm confused as to how this could not be working, just by looking at it, everything seems to match up

This is how I'm trying to map it:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DataProduct dataProduct = mapper.readValue(json, DataProduct.class);
```

This is the json string I'm trying to map:

```
{ 
   "data":[ 
      { 
         "barcode":"4412312324",
         "description":"Southern Fries",
         "price":2.3,
         "onHand":0.0,
         "Aisle":"25R",
         "Location Code":"101",
         "Section":"Grocery",
         "Date_Removed":"42:53.4",
      }
   ],
   "meta":{ 
      "store":"Store 1",
      "originated":"2020-02-07T20:49:38.105629500Z",
      "correlationId":"a5ea816d-6589-4251-b951-d022a0159352"
   }
}
```

Here's the classes I'm trying to map to:

```
@Value
public class DataProduct {
  private List<Product> data;
  private DataProductMetadata meta;
}
```

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Value
public class Product {
  @NonNull
  private String barcode;
  @NonNull
  private String description;
  @NonNull
  private Double price;
  @NonNull
  private Double onHand;

  @JsonIgnore
  @JsonUnwrapped
  private Map<String, Object> customFields;

  @JsonAnyGetter
  public Map<String, Object> getCustomFields() {
    return customFields;
  }

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setCustomField(String name, Object value) {
    customFields.put(name, value);
  }
}
```

```
@Builder
@Value
public class DataProductMetadata {
  @NonNull
  private final String store;
  @NonNull
  private final Instant originated;
  @NonNull
  private final String correlationId;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some issues in your json and your code as well:

1. Your json object `data` has a redundant `,`. It causes a parsing exception.

   "Date_Removed":"42:53.4",
2. You will get the NullPointerException in the `setCustomField` method because `customFields` hasn't been initialized yet.
3. `originated` in the `DataProductMetadata` is not a serializable object. You can use `Date` instead or others which is serializable.

You can see the fixed version here

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DataProduct {
  private List<Product> data;
  private DataProductMetadata meta;
}

@Builder
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DataProductMetadata {
   @NonNull
   private String store;
   @NonNull
   private Date originated;
   @NonNull
   private String correlationId;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Product {
   @NonNull
   private String barcode;
   @NonNull
   private String description;
   @NonNull
   private Double price;
   @NonNull
   private Double onHand;

  @JsonIgnore
   @JsonUnwrapped
   private Map<String, Object> customFields =new HashMap<>();;

   @JsonAnyGetter
   public Map<String, Object> getCustomFields() {
      return customFields;
   }

   @JsonAnySetter
   public void setCustomField(String name, Object value) {
      customFields.put(name, value);
   }
}
```

Due to some lombok's annotations are used, you should add lombok library to your project but I guessed you have used this library already.

Comment: Shouldn't those be set to customFields by the @JsonAnySetter and @JsonAnyGetter?

Comment: Well, I debugged your code and found some interesting thing here. Ignore my last answer because I didn't check your unwrapped object. The updated answer is being written.

Comment: Thank you!  #2 turned out to be the solution.  #1 was just due to a copy and paste error when writing up the question and #3 wound up not causing any issues for me.

Comment: @Tran Ho, I am getting the similar errorcom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A. I have one field "HashMap" in my class which is initialised as empty bet. But, the field is not initialised while calling the setter methods. So, can you please summarise the usage of "@JsonIgnore", "@JsonUnwrapped" and "@JsonAnySetter" here ? which one should I use to fix the error ?